# Объектно-ориентированное программирование на Python. Поясните, пожалуйста, как вот в этом примере сделать пункты 5,6

Tags: python-3.x

```
#  Создайте класс Word. (Вспомните, какое зарезервированное слово используется для создания класса).
class Word:
# Добавьте свойства text (класс будет хранить слово) и part (часть речи, которой является слово. Например, существительное, прилагательное и т.п.). Для добавления свойств воспользуйтесь методом __init__.
    text = "any words"
    part = "глагол"

   def text_call(self):
        word = self.text
        print("название слова -  " + word)

    def __init__(self, text, part):
        self.text = text
        self.part = part

#Создайте экземпляр класса Word, передав в качестве параметров любое слово и указав его часть речи.
word_1 = Word("бабочка", "существительное")
word_2 = Word("пила", "глагол")
word_3 = Word("яркая", "прилагательное")
word_4 = Word("нектар", "существительное")
word_5 = Word("утром", "наречие")

print(word_1.text, word_2.text, word_3.text, word_4.text,word_5.text)
print(word_1.part, word_2.part, word_3.part, word_4.part,word_5.part)

#Создайте класс Sentence. (по аналогии с п. 1).
class Sentence:
# 5. Добавьте свойство content. (по аналогии с п. 2).

    content = [0, 1, 2, 3]

    def __init__(self, content=[]):
     self.content = content



#Пояснение к дальнейшему коду: content будет хранить список целых чисел, например [0, 1]. Эти номера необходимы для выбора слов из заранее созданного массива, чтобы сформировать предложение.
#Пример массива:
#words = [["бабочка", "сущ"],
#         ["пила", "глагол"],
#         ["нектар", "сущ"],
#         ["утром", "наречие"]]
#Если content == [0, 2], получим предложение вида «Бабочка нектар».

#6. Создайте из массива (можете взять приведённый выше или придумать свой) список, каждый элемент которого является экземпляром класса Word. Примечание: список list (назовём его words) — отдельная переменная, не относящаяся к классам Word и Sentence.
```

Answer (score 0):

Как и написано в пункте 5, делать его следует *по аналогии с п. 2*.

А именно, необходимо определить метод `__init__`:

```py
class Sentence:
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content = content
```

Пункт 6 можно легко выполнить, воспользовавшись списковым включением:

```py
li = [
    ['бабочка', 'существительное'],
    ['нектар', 'существительное'],
    ['утром', 'наречие'],
    ['пила', 'глагол'],
]
words = [Word(text, part) for text, part in li]  # или [Word(*x) for x in li]
```

Comment: А почему li не определяется?

Comment: И как потом выполнить пункт                                                                                                 
7. Добавьте в класс Sentence метод show, составляющий предложение. Метод должен перебирать числа из свойства content и подставлять соответствующие слова, которые хранятся в свойстве text экземпляров класса Word. Данные извлекаем из списка words, который получили на прошлом шаге. При соединении слов в предложение не забудьте добавить пробел между словами.

Comment: и 8. Добавьте в класс Sentence метод show_parts, отображающий, какие части речи входят в предложение. По аналогии с п. 7 перебирайте в цикле числа из свойства content и сохраняйте результат в отдельный список. Учтите, что части речи могут повторяться, но список не должен содержать дубликаты.